# Erro de codificação ao inserir dados no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Galera, eu estou começando agora e estou tentando criar um pequeno formulário com PHP e MySQL que envie as informações do formulário para o banco, mas estou com um pequeno problema. Ao inserir os dados no banco, quando vou visualizar na tabela os dados estão com problema de codificação, por exemplo, quando eu Cadastro um usuário com nome "João..." na tabela do banco ele aparece como "JoÃ£o...", sendo que o collate do banco já está como utf8_general_ci e o da tabela também. Como resolver isso?

Segue abaixo a foto do código e do erro 
[image: Codigo da conexão]

[image: Usuário cadastrado no banco]

Comment: Tenta adiocionar `mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conexao);` em seu código

Comment: Funcionou, Grato! :)